# Phonegap / Cordova database connectivity

Tags: jquery, cordova, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-build

I'm new to mobile app development. Where can I get sample applications or codes for Phonegap / Cordova database connectivity using php, jquery and mysql. Thank you in advance. I want to make a sample login and register app.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Phonegap/Cordova does not run PHP or MySQL.

If you want your application to connect to some external DB, then creating a "webserver" with PHP which echoes Json results, and accessing it through Ajax is the best option. Never let your users connect directly to your external database, as they can always sniff it and get your credentials.

If you want to store the dababase on each client's device, there's a lot of options. You can always use webStorage (key=>value pairs). There are many plugins for adding SQLite database to your project, as [this one](https://github.com/msopentech/cordova-plugin-websql/). Also, you can also use [SQL.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/), which is just SQLite converted to Javascript using emscripten.

As you want to create a login/register, then the best option is creating it using PHP on the server side (a back-end that users can't access directly, only your app) and access it using Ajax. Do not forget to set the CORS headers correctly, so you can make cross-domain requests with Ajax from your phonegap app. If you allow me to make a suggestion, take a look on [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/), it makes the creation of APIs/webservices a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate this help greatly

Comment: Remember to, if you've got the answers you need, always mark the answer as accepted, so other people with the same question as you will find it faster :)